# Переход по ссылке на файл или объект-родитель в Sublime Text 3

Tags: django, sublime-text, pycharm

Перехожу с Pycharm на ST3, и очень не хватает некоторых возможностей для проектов на Django.

В частности, если в шаблон включены другие шаблоны с помощью {% include %} или в артрибуте href есть ссылка на файл, я могу перейти и посмотреть на них

```
{% block css %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static 'table/css/table.css' %}>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="header sidebar-spacer">
        <div class="settings-button"></div>
        {% include 'table/template1.html' %}
    </div>
    {% include 'table/template2.html' %}
    <div class="footer sidebar-spacer"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

В указанном примере я могу по клику перейти и посомтреть на исходный код `table.css`, шаблонов `template1, template2`.

В представлениях аналогичная картина

```
class ElementListView(ListView):

template_name = "table/table.html"
model = Element
...
```

Я не могу посомтреть исходный код метода `ListView`, шаблон `table.html`

Есть плагины для ST, которые будут имитировать работу Pycharm и будут полезны для проектов на Python/Django?

Comment: Даже бесплатный пичарм, лучше саблайма, я считаю.

Comment: while1pass, т. к. у Вас в путях не используются переменные, достаточно плагина [**Open Include**](https://github.com/titoBouzout/Open-Include). [**Демонстрация**](http://i.imgur.com/Z5vGuFq.gif). Никогда не пользовался Django Templates, но вот если там как в Jinja2 используются конструкции вроде `{{SITEURL}}/{{ THEME_STATIC_DIR }}/bower-components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`, для таких путей не знаю, как быть. Спасибо.

Comment: while1pass, да, и данный вопрос [**FuzzyFilePath**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FuzzyFilePath) не решает, но рекомендую обратить внимание на этот пакет, упрощающий работу с относительными путями. Спасибо.

Comment: while1pass, есть какие-либо замечания? Могу как ответ опубликовать данные комментарии? Спасибо.

Comment: да, опубликуйте. я не стал настаивать на публикации в ответе, подумал, вы скромничаете.

Comment: while1pass, последние версии Open Include не работают у меня должным образом + разработчик не принимает issues. Есть альтернатива — [**Open URL**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Open%20URL). И я создал там [**issue**](https://github.com/noahcoad/open-url/issues/49), чтобы была поддержка шаблонов. Спасибо.